# Unusual behavior when uploading ionic project to a web server instead of uploading it in the app store

Tags: html, ionic-framework

Okay so I know that the ionic framework is mainly used to build hybrid apps and upload them to the App Store or the Play Store, however, I decided to try something different. It is still under construction, but I tried to upload a project of mine to the web. I had a domain, so I used filezilla and uploaded the **www** folder from my project. Everything worked like a charm. Then I accessed the website using a PC. Everything seemed fine, unfortunately when I accessed the website using a smartphone there were several problems.

1. The home page is supposed to lack a navigation bar (in the ion-view I have a line **hide-nav-bar="true"**), yet when using smartphone it is filled with white space.
2. I have a search input as a subheader in two different tabs, which is displayed as just whitespace too.

As I said before these two problems occur only when the website is accessed by a smartphone or a tablet.

**Here is the code of the home tab (home.html)**

```
<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true">
  <ion-content class="splash padding">
    <div class="branding">
      <h3>I haven't been everywhere, but it's on my list!</h3>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**Here is the code from one of the tabs, using a search input**

```
<ion-view view-title="Newest posts">
<div class="bar bar-subheader 
  item-input-inset bar-light">
  <label class="item-input-wrapper">
    <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
    <input type="search" ng-model="postQuery" placeholder="Search for post">
  </label>
</div>
<ion-content class="has-subheader">
...
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

[image]

Actually here the white space is not visible, because of the background of the website, but the next picture makes it obvious.

[image]

Comment: have you only tried it on android devices? what mobile browsers have you tried?

Comment: Oh yes, that's what I forgot to mention. I have tried with android devices only. The browsers were CM browser and google chrome. Unfortunately I don't have access to an ios device.

Comment: ok I may have figured it out, I looked at your page on my phone, if you have a subheader with no header than you will just have a blank space. You either need to make the subheader a header on your home page and on your contact me page or you need to add a header. subheader has a absolute position in relationship to where the header should be. does that make sense?

Comment: It sure does, but I don't want neither a header nor a subheader in the home tab, whereas in the feed tab I want them both, a header and a subheader. If my answer doesn't make sense, can you look at the code I have provided?

Comment: I am guessing the issue is that android has outdated and fragmented web views and browser engines, if you want to guarantee uniform performance across mobile browsers and platforms you are going to have to use ionic.Platform to find out what platform it is and make changes to your template using something like ng-switch or ng-if etc to change the html layout to display correctly based on the device. I am guessing the android browsers can't handle whatever the hide-nav-bar is trying to do. So if someone is on android you may need to change your template a little to make it look good.

Comment: that is all I can think of. ionic platform: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.Platform/
ng-if: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Comment: Okay, I see, I have one question, though. I saw that the set of utility methods which ionic.Platform provides are working mainly depending on the type of platform the device is installed on, so will the same principles apply if the project is uploaded to a web server and being used as a simple website?

Comment: hmm...honestly i dont know...i would just throw a ionic.platform.isAndroid() and try to throw alert and visit the site from your phone. I haven't tried it. if you can't use ionic platform there has to be tons of other ways to detect the system that is access the site and then make changes based on that.

Comment: Mhm, that was my guess too, thanks

Comment: may be a long shot but if hid-nav-bar doesnt work you could use ng-class on the home and about me page and try adding a class with display:none. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass